# EF Core needlessly executing both branches of conditional assignment logic

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am experiencing an issue with EF Core where if I assign a property with branching logic, both branches are executed (rather than just the branch where condition == true).

In the first code sample below, I have replaced the conditional I am actually trying to test with one that I know to always be false to verify my question. In my real-world example, the table that `MyEntities` maps to has no records with an `Id` as high as 1000.

However, when I call this method, I can see in my output window first the query to get where `Id` is 1000 (returns no results) and then `N` SQL queries trying to retrieve the `Count` at the end of the first branch's LINQ pipeline being executed. If the condition is always false, these queries to get the `Count` should never execute (the other `(int?)null` branch should only ever be executed), correct?

I suspect this could possibly be a bug with EF Core or my EF Core Provider (Pomelo MySQL), but I wanted to make sure I didn't misunderstand how EF and/or branching in LINQ works. Both branches should not be executed in a conditional, correct? If you think it might be a bug, how do I know whether it is with EF Core or the provider I am using?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyEntityDto>> GetMyEntityDtosAsync() =>
    await DbContext.MyEntities
                   .Select(l => new MyEntityDto
                   {
                       Id = l.Id,
                       RuleCount = l.Id == 1000  // known to always be false
                           ? l.MyLinkedEntity
                              .Where(s => s.MyBoolean)
                              .FirstOrDefault()
                              .MyManyToMany
                              .Count
                           : (int?)null
                   });
```

The actual query I am trying to implement looks more like below to gracefully handle if each `MyEntity` has no `MyLinkedEntity`s where `MyBoolean == true`. This throws exceptions in the cases where there are not any `MyLinkedEntity`s satisfying those conditions (supposed to be handled by the conditional). Is there a workaround logic I might be able to try?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyEntityDto>> GetMyEntityDtosAsync() =>
    await DbContext.MyEntities
                   .Select(l => new MyEntityDto
                   {
                       Id = l.Id,
                       RuleCount = l.MyLinkedEntity.Any(s => s.MyBoolean)
                           ? l.MyLinkedEntity
                              .Where(s => s.MyBoolean)
                              .FirstOrDefault()
                              .MyManyToMany
                              .Count
                           : (int?)null
                   });
```

**Update:** adding POCOs

```
public class MyEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyLinkedEntityId { get; set; }
    public MyLinkedEntity MyLinkedEntity { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyLinkedEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool MyBoolean { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyManyToMany {
    public int MyLinkedEntityId { get; set; }
    public MyLinkedEntity MyLinkedEntity { get; set; }
    public int MyOtherLinkedEntity { get; set; }
    public MyOtherLinkedEntity MyOtherLinkedEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my guess: EF is retrieving all data that could be a part of the final projection then evaluating your conditional logic client-side with the results.

The error you're getting is due to the fact that you're referencing `MyLinkedEntity.MyManyToMany.Count` with what could be a null reference returned from `FirstOrDefault()`.

Since you haven't posted the POCOs I'm winging it, but work with the set of entities of the type of `l.MyLinkedEntity` in your current code, group by the principal (the entity you were projecting from) and project `ManyToMany.Count` *before* calling `FirstOrDefault()`.  Hopefully this works, I'm not home to test :P

```
DbContext.MyLinkedEntities
    .GroupBy( mle => mle.MyEntity )
    .Select( g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        RuleCount = g.Where( s => s.MyBoolean )
            .Select( s => ( int? )s.ManyToMany.Count )
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }
```

Comment: Your guess makes perfect sense. Unfortunately, this solution won't work. I get `An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator`.

Comment: whoops, that's right.  post the POCOs and I'll try to help you more than the updated answer

Comment: See **Update** at the bottom of the question for POCOs. Will try your updated answer and share results. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! Since I am assigning a bunch of other properties in the `Select()`, I replaced the `GroupBy()` with `&& s.MyEntity == g` in the `Where()`. but, your solution seems to work cleanly.